# Time and Attandance, store records

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a time registering system for employees.
I've started with saving the time as "**Datetime**" in `mysql`.
The problem is when i have two columns with datetime the registered time will only fill one column, the second (depending on sign in or out) is set to **"0000-00-00 00:00:00"**. Now when I like to echo out a table with time records i also echo out the "empty" fields. I tried to use a if statement, but then my table didn't work verywell, and I can't just use "Order" in the "Select". Is there any better way, to store time records, or should i do some filtering with a php script?

**php**

```
<table>
    <?php 
     //Loop out the result
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      echo "<tr>";      
         echo "<td>" .$row['usr_stamp_in']."</td>";             
          echo "<td>" .$row['usr_stamp_out']."</td>";      
     echo "</tr>";
    }
     ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: Instead of having the <td> tags inside of the If clause you could put them outside, and only use the IF sentence on the value to be displayed, that way your table should be displayed correctly

Comment: Thank you. Now the table looks good, but i got a new issue. I got blanc fields.. i think i need to parse the time with a php script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the table display correctly, you will want to output the  in either case. So use your if to set up an output string, which might be empty eg.

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  echo "<tr>";
  if($row['usr_stamp_in'] == "0000-00-00 00:00:00") {
    $usr_stamp_in_display = ''; 
  } else {
    $usr_stamp_in_display = $row['usr_stamp_in']; 
  }
  if($row['usr_stamp_out'] == "0000-00-00 00:00:00") {
    $usr_stamp_out_display = ''; 
  } else {
    $usr_stamp_out_display = $row['usr_stamp_out']; 
  }

  echo "<td>$usr_stamp_in_display</td>";
  echo "<td>$usr_stamp_out_display</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Or shorter:

```
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      echo "<tr>";
      $usr_stamp_in_display = ($row['usr_stamp_in'] == "0000-00-00 00:00:00") ? '' : $row['usr_stamp_in']; 
      $usr_stamp_out_display = ($row['usr_stamp_out'] == "0000-00-00 00:00:00") ? '' : $row['usr_stamp_out'];

      echo "<td>$usr_stamp_in_display</td>";
      echo "<td>$usr_stamp_out_display</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Very nice code! It fixes the table problems, but giving me new ones ;D I need to code a more complex script, because now i get one date from stamp_in on one row, and stamp_out comes first on second row.

Answer (score 0):

I would always recommend storing the time as INT(11). Simply store the unix timestamp that you get from time() in php.

This will allow you to format it really easily using the php date function :)

Comment: I guess maby this must be my choise. To make the look of the table readable and to calculate working hrs, i need to parse time_in and time_out. I need to code a more complex system.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  echo "<tr>" .
         "<td>";
  if ($row['usr_stamp_in'] != "0000-00-00 00:00:00") {
     echo $row['usr_stamp_in'];
  }
  echo  "</td>" .
         "<td>";
  if ($row['usr_stamp_out'] != "0000-00-00 00:00:00") {
      echo $row['usr_stamp_out'];
  }
  echo "</td>";
}
 echo "</tr>";
}
 ?>
 </table>
```

This way you avoid your table looking strange due to some cols not having the same amount of rows as the others

Comment: Thank you. This fixes the table. But i get a new issue. The time table isn't matching days.. i need to code a more complex php script.